# Add extra plugins to CKEditor using bower

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, bower

I use bower to manage my js packages. I installed CKEditor into bower directory and it worked fine.

The question is: how should I add external plugins to ckeditor? I read here http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Supports-Bower-and-Composer that this is possible by using extraPlugins property. But obviously I should somehow download plugin and add it to ckeditor/plugins folder. I'm quite new to bower but as I understand I shouldn't manually add any files or folders into bower directory. Instead I should use `bower install plugin_name` or something like that.

So, if I simple write it like:

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('pageContent', {
        extraPlugins: 'Syntaxhighlighter Interface'
    });
```

I got an error that the plugins is not found

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can see you can't just use Bower to care about the CKEditor plugins but at least you can add plugins from an external folder with this command:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );
```

`/myplugins/sample/` is a path to the folder where the `plugin.js` file is relative to the web root. `sample` is the name of the plugin.

Check out the docs on this:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal

Answer (score 3):

With the page you linked mentions that Ckeditor iteself can be downloaded with `bower` but not the plugins. After you download the plugins you need to enable them with the `extraPlugins` option. To download the actual plugin I would use the plugin's download link like so:

`bower install http://mydomain/somefile.zip`

Comment: I can use bower to install custom js plugins which are not in bower repository? Just using link? I didn't know that, but how can I tell bower to install the "somefile.zip" into ckeditor/plugins folder then

Comment: You will just manually have to move it to the right directory after install.

Comment: Well, if I update ckeditor it will rewrite plugins directory and I'll lost manual changes

Comment: @Victor Yes, but that is true either ways, whether you install the plugin or not. You would have had to redo all the settings when you update.

Comment: Just keep somewhere the copy of your plugins directory and config file, and then replace the updated ones. That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [@codehitman's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385595/241211) you can manage the plugin via bower with at least two approaches:

1. Via CLI:

   ```
   bower install panelbutton=https://download.ckeditor.com/panelbutton/releases/panelbutton_4.7.2.zip --save
   ```

   The previous line will download the "panelbutton" addon and rename the downloaded addon to "panelbutton" (specified before the `=`) and the `--save` will write the command to *bower.json* (totally optional).
2. Via *bower.json*:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "panelbutton": "https://download.ckeditor.com/panelbutton/releases/panelbutton_4.7.2.zip",
     "colorbutton": "https://download.ckeditor.com/colorbutton/releases/colorbutton_4.7.2.zip"
   }
   ```

   Just add the name you want to save the downloaded addon and the download url.

---

EXTRA: since you might want to store the downloaded addons into a ckeditor path, you can accomplish creating *.bowerrc* and pasting the following:

```
{
  "directory" : "my/path/to/ckeditor/addons"
}
```

WARNING: If there is only a js on the package, bower renames it to index.js. I solved it running a postinstall script like this (adapt to your needs).

```
mv ./web/libraries/panelbutton/index.js ./web/libraries/panelbutton/plugin.js
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try adding the following line to your bower.json file:

"ckeditor": "#full/4.4.7"

This should install all plugins for you!